# How to use addEventListener on multiple input fields to invoke keyup event on them in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener, keyup, event-delegation

I have multiple input fields on which I want to apply onkeyup event on all of them with passing ID of textbox as a parameter. I want multiple keyup event because I want to handle some calculations on the basis of input ID. I tried but failed. Please suggest some solutions.

```
function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
            return "<td>"
            +"<select class='js-example-placeholder-single js-states form-control loadcompany' id='lcompanyselect' onchange='getDriverAndTruck()';></select>"
            +"<input type='button' value='+' class='qty-plus' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#edit_co'></td>"
            +"<td><select class='js-example-placeholder-single js-states form-control' id='ldriverselect'></select>"
            +"<input type='button' value='+' class='qty-plus' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#edit_driver'></td>"
            +"<td class=''><select class='js-example-placeholder-single js-states form-control' id='ltruckselect'></select>"
            +"<input type='button' value='+' class='qty-plus' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#edit_truck'></td>"
            +"<td><input name='tripnumber' type='text' class='form-control' id='ltripnumber'/></td>"
            +"<td><select id='lsubtrip' name='subtrip' class='js-example-placeholder-single js-states form-control'>"
            +"<option disabled selected></option><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option>"
            +"<option value='3'>3</option></select>"
            +"<td><input name='date' type='date' class='form-control' id='ldate'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='pickupcity' type='text' class='form-control' id='lpickupcity'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='pickupstate' type='text' class='form-control' id='lpickupstate'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='deliverydate' type='date' class='form-control' id='ldeliverydate'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='delivercity' type='text' class='form-control' id='ldelivercity'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='deliverstate' type='text' class='form-control' id='ldeliverstate'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='loadnumber' type='text' class='form-control' id='lloadnumber'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='loadrate' type='text' class='form-control' id='lloadrate' onkeyup='countload();'/>"
            +"<span id='lerrormessage'></span></td>"
            +"<td><input name='dispatchfee' type='text' class='form-control' id='ldispatchfee' readonly/></td>"
            +'<td><input name="fuel" type="text" class="form-control count" id="lfuel" onkeyup=\"lcount('"+lfuel+"');\"/></td>'
            +"<td><input name='cardfee' type='text' class='form-control count' id='lcardfee' onkeyup='lcount('lcardfee');'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='onloadrepair' type='text' class='form-control count' id='lonloadrepair' onkeyup='lcount('lonloadrepair');'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='shoprepair' type='text' class='form-control count' id='lshoprepair' onkeyup='lcount('lshoprepair');'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='trailerrent' type='text' class='form-control count' id='ltrailerrent' onkeyup='lcount('ltrailerrent');'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='comcheck' type='text' class='form-control count' id='lcomcheck' onkeyup='lcount('lcomcheck');'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='advance' type='text' class='form-control count' id='ladvance' onkeyup='lcount('ladvance');'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='miscellenous' type='text' class='form-control count' id='lmiscellenous' onkeyup='lcount('lmiscellenous');'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='misc1' type='text' class='form-control count' id='lmisc1' onkeyup='lcount('lmisc1');'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='misc2' type='text' class='form-control count' id='lmisc2' onkeyup='lcount('lmisc2');'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='misc3' type='text' class='form-control count' id='lmisc3' onkeyup='lcount('lmisc3');'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='misc4' type='text' class='form-control count' id='lmisc4' onkeyup='lcount('lmisc4');'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='total' type='text' class='form-control' id='ltotal' readonly/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='layover' type='text' class='form-control count' id='llayover' onkeyup='lcount('llayover');'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='addtl1' type='text' class='form-control count' id='laddtl1' onkeyup='lcount('laddtl1')'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='addtl2' type='text' class='form-control count' id='laddtl2' onkeyup='lcount('laddtl2');'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='addtl3' type='text' class='form-control count' id='laddtl3' onkeyup='lcount('laddtl3');'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='subtotal' type='text' class='form-control' id='lsubtotal' readonly/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='paymentmode' type='text' class='form-control' id='lpaymentmode'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='pay' type='text' class='form-control' id='lpay' onkeyup='countleftpay();'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='notes' type='text' class='form-control' id='lnotes'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='grandtotal' type='text' class='form-control' id='lgrandtotal' readonly/></td>"
            +"<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-info text-info' onclick='savetriplist();'>Submit</button>" 
        }
```

[image: Error screenshot]
[image: table row screenshot]

Comment: *"I tried but failed"* Please include your attempt(s) so we can help you understand what is wrong. -> [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You mean you want to define one event handler that applies on some inputs or you want to have some onkeyup handler on every input?

Comment: I want onkeyup handler on every input

Comment: @Reyno I tried this way : var inputhandler = document.getElementsByClassName('count');
for(var i =0; i < inputhandler.length; i++){
  inputhandler[i].addEventListener("keyup", count());
}

Comment: There is no element with class name `count` in your code so `document.getElementsByClassName('count');` won't get anything.

Comment: @Rakhi ... 1/2 ... most probably the OP is in need of just as single event listener which will (has to) be assigned/attached to the very element node where the return value of `GetDynamicTextBox` gets/was rendered into. Thus it was nice to have provided with the example code the meta/outer html structure as well.

Comment: @Rakhi ... 2/2 ... The to be used technique is referred to as [Event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) ... [David Walsh :: How JavaScript Event Delegation Works](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) ... [javascript.info :: Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) ... [jQuery :: Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: If possible, can  you please show me an example to use keyup event on multiple input and I want to compare or check which input field is entered and do some calculations.?

Answer (score 0):

From the above comments ...

> *1/2 ... most probably the OP is in need of just as single event listener which will (has to) be assigned/attached to the very element node where the return value of GetDynamicTextBox gets/was rendered into. Thus it was nice to have provided with the example code the meta/outer html structure as well.*

> *2/2 ... The to be used technique is referred to as [Event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) ... [David Walsh :: How JavaScript Event Delegation Works](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) ... [javascript.info :: Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) ... [jQuery :: Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)*

```js
function createTextBoxMarkup(/* value */) {
  return `
    <td>
      <input name = "deliverydate" type="date" class="form-control" id="ldeliverydate"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name = "delivercity" type="text" class="form-control" id="ldelivercity"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name = "deliverstate" type="text" class="form-control" id="ldeliverstate"/>
    </td>`;
}

function handleTextBoxKeyup(evt) {
  const elmInput = evt.target;
  const { type, name, id, value } = elmInput;

  console.log({ elmInput, type, name, id, value });  
}

function init() {
  const elmTBody = document.querySelector('tbody');
  const elmTr = document.createElement('tr');

  elmTr.innerHTML = createTextBoxMarkup();
  elmTBody.appendChild(elmTr);

  // register 'keyup' event type.
  elmTBody.addEventListener('keyup', handleTextBoxKeyup);
}
init();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 83%; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

***Edit** according to further questions of the OP*

> *Can I use something like*
>
> ```
> function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
>   return '<td><input type="text" id="lfuel" onkeyup="count('lfuel');"/></td><td><input type="text" id="lcardfee" onkeyup="count('lcardfee');" /></td>'
> }
> ```
>
> *and then define that count like :*
>
> ```
> function count(id) {
>   if (id == 'lfuel') {
>     var a = document.getElementById('lfuel').value;
>   }
>   if (id == 'lcardfee') {
>     var b = document.getElementById('lcardfee').value;}
> }
> ```
>
> *– Rakhi*

> *Above solution did not worked for me. – Rakhi*

The implementation of `handleTextBoxKeyup` is just example code which demonstrates how information can be extracted from the `event` object. Of cause the OP can implement the handler according to her/his needs e.g. invoking a `count` function from within the handler whenever the `event.target` is an input element of type `"text"`.

```js
function createTextBoxMarkup(/* value */) {
  return `
    <td>
      <input name = "deliverydate" type="date" class="form-control" id="ldeliverydate"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name = "delivercity" type="text" class="form-control" id="ldelivercity"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name = "deliverstate" type="text" class="form-control" id="ldeliverstate"/>
    </td>`;
}

function isTextTypeInputElement(elmNode) {
  return (
    (elmNode?.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input') &&
    (elmNode?.type === 'text')
  );  
}

function count(elmTextInput) {
  const {  name, id, value } = elmTextInput;

  console.log({ elmTextInput, name, id, value }); 
}

function handleTextBoxKeyup(evt) {
  const elmNode = evt.target;
  if (isTextTypeInputElement(elmNode)) {
  
    count(elmNode);
  }
}

function init() {
  const elmTBody = document.querySelector('tbody');
  const elmTr = document.createElement('tr');

  elmTr.innerHTML = createTextBoxMarkup();
  elmTBody.appendChild(elmTr);

  // register 'keyup' event type.
  elmTBody.addEventListener('keyup', handleTextBoxKeyup);
}
init();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 83%; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can I use something like function GetDynamicTextBox(value) { return '<td><input type="text" id="lfuel" onkeyup="count('lfuel');" /></td><td><input type="text" id="lcardfee" onkeyup="count('lcardfee');" /></td>'}

Comment: and then define that count like : function count(id){ if(id=='lfuel'){ var a = document.getElementById('lfuel').value; } if(id=='lcardfee'){var b = document.getElementById('lcardfee').value;}}

Comment: Above solution did not worked for me.

Comment: @Rakhi ... the implementation of `handleTextBoxKeyup` is just example code which demonstrates how information can be extracted from the `event` object. Of cause the OP can implement the handler according to her/his needs e.g. invoking a `count` function from within the handler whenever the `event.target` is an input element of type `"text"`.

Comment: I got your point but I want to know that how to pass input id to count() function as a string. Example <input type="text" id="lfuel" name="fuel" onkeyup="count('lfuel')" />. I am getting error here.

Comment: @Rakhi ... I doubt the OP got the point. Otherwise the OP was able to change the example's handler function her/himself towards invoking the OP's `count` function from within the handler with a valid `id` value. ... btw ... The above example code did change in order to just demonstrate that. And of cause one does not need to pass the `id` value since one already can provide the correct `input` element.