# How to use addEventListener on multiple input fields to invoke keyup event on them in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener, keyup, event-delegation

I have multiple input fields on which I want to apply onkeyup event on all of them with passing ID of textbox as a parameter. I want multiple keyup event because I want to handle some calculations on the basis of input ID. I tried but failed. Please suggest some solutions.

```
function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
            return "<td>"
            +"<select class='js-example-placeholder-single js-states form-control loadcompany' id='lcompanyselect' onchange='getDriverAndTruck()';></select>"
            +"<input type='button' value='+' class='qty-plus' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#edit_co'></td>"
            +"<td><select class='js-example-placeholder-single js-states form-control' id='ldriverselect'></select>"
            +"<input type='button' value='+' class='qty-plus' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#edit_driver'></td>"
            +"<td class=''><select class='js-example-placeholder-single js-states form-control' id='ltruckselect'></select>"
            +"<input type='button' value='+' class='qty-plus' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#edit_truck'></td>"
            +"<td><input name='tripnumber' type='text' class='form-control' id='ltripnumber'/></td>"
            +"<td><select id='lsubtrip' name='subtrip' class='js-example-placeholder-single js-states form-control'>"
            +"<option disabled selected></option><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option>"
            +"<option value='3'>3</option></select>"
            +"<td><input name='date' type='date' class='form-control' id='ldate'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='pickupcity' type='text' class='form-control' id='lpickupcity'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='pickupstate' type='text' class='form-control' id='lpickupstate'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='deliverydate' type='date' class='form-control' id='ldeliverydate'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='delivercity' type='text' class='form-control' id='ldelivercity'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='deliverstate' type='text' class='form-control' id='ldeliverstate'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='loadnumber' type='text' class='form-control' id='lloadnumber'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='loadrate' type='text' class='form-control' id='lloadrate' onkeyup='countload();'/>"
            +"<span id='lerrormessage'></span></td>"
            +"<td><input name='dispatchfee' type='text' class='form-control' id='ldispatchfee' readonly/></td>"
            +'<td><input name="fuel" type="text" class="form-control count" id="lfuel" onkeyup=\"lcount('"+lfuel+"');\"/></td>'
            +"<td><input name='cardfee' type='text' class='form-control count' id='lcardfee' onkeyup='lcount('lcardfee');'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='onloadrepair' type='text' class='form-control count' id='lonloadrepair' onkeyup='lcount('lonloadrepair');'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='shoprepair' type='text' class='form-control count' id='lshoprepair' onkeyup='lcount('lshoprepair');'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='trailerrent' type='text' class='form-control count' id='ltrailerrent' onkeyup='lcount('ltrailerrent');'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='comcheck' type='text' class='form-control count' id='lcomcheck' onkeyup='lcount('lcomcheck');'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='advance' type='text' class='form-control count' id='ladvance' onkeyup='lcount('ladvance');'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='miscellenous' type='text' class='form-control count' id='lmiscellenous' onkeyup='lcount('lmiscellenous');'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='misc1' type='text' class='form-control count' id='lmisc1' onkeyup='lcount('lmisc1');'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='misc2' type='text' class='form-control count' id='lmisc2' onkeyup='lcount('lmisc2');'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='misc3' type='text' class='form-control count' id='lmisc3' onkeyup='lcount('lmisc3');'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='misc4' type='text' class='form-control count' id='lmisc4' onkeyup='lcount('lmisc4');'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='total' type='text' class='form-control' id='ltotal' readonly/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='layover' type='text' class='form-control count' id='llayover' onkeyup='lcount('llayover');'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='addtl1' type='text' class='form-control count' id='laddtl1' onkeyup='lcount('laddtl1')'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='addtl2' type='text' class='form-control count' id='laddtl2' onkeyup='lcount('laddtl2');'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='addtl3' type='text' class='form-control count' id='laddtl3' onkeyup='lcount('laddtl3');'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='subtotal' type='text' class='form-control' id='lsubtotal' readonly/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='paymentmode' type='text' class='form-control' id='lpaymentmode'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='pay' type='text' class='form-control' id='lpay' onkeyup='countleftpay();'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='notes' type='text' class='form-control' id='lnotes'/></td>"
            +"<td><input name='grandtotal' type='text' class='form-control' id='lgrandtotal' readonly/></td>"
            +"<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-info text-info' onclick='savetriplist();'>Submit</button>" 
        }
```

[image: Screenshot to display error]
[image: Screenshot to display table row structure]

Comment: What have you tried and why did that fail? Have you tried using JQuery, which should make this a very simple one-line code solution? Have you tried plain JavaScript with something like: `const inputElements = document.querySelectorAll('input')` and then iterating over each input element?

Comment: @KyleNakamura I just want to know how to pass input id as a parameter inside onkeyup="count();". Suppose I have <input type="text" id="lfuel" name="fuel"  onkeyup="count('lfuel');" /> So I want to pass id="lfuel" as a parameter to count() function.

Comment: You can pass in `this.id`, e.g. `<input id="Ifuel" onkeyup="count(this.id)">`. Although you should probably avoid inline JS unless it's React, Angular, Lit, etc.

Comment: Why did the OP  choose to delete this Q. ... [How to use addEventListener on multiple input fields to invoke keyup event on them in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70286371/how-to-use-addeventlistener-on-multiple-input-fields-to-invoke-keyup-event-on-th) ... 4 hours ago only to open another Q. (this very one) of the exactly same subject and title?

Comment: The Q. explicitly asks for the use of [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), which is, I suppose, due to replace each text input element's inline scripting. Thus the answer and the code examples provided yesterday, which make use of event delegation are perfectly solving the OP's problem. Why, for still unsolved problems, did the OP not continue answering the questions which where asked by the people trying to help the OP, and why did the OP not continue asking for further support?

Comment: @Rakhi ... 1/2 ... most probably the OP is in need of just as single event listener which will (has to) be assigned/attached to the very element node where the return value of GetDynamicTextBox gets/was rendered into. Thus it was nice to have provided with the example code the meta/outer html structure as well.

Comment: @Rakhi ... 2/2 ... The to be used technique is referred to as [Event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) ... [David Walsh :: How JavaScript Event Delegation Works](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) ... [javascript.info :: Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) ... [jQuery :: Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: I have already got the solution of my question. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

From the above comments ...

> *1/2 ... most probably the OP is in need of just as single event listener which will (has to) be assigned/attached to the very element node where the return value of GetDynamicTextBox gets/was rendered into. Thus it was nice to have provided with the example code the meta/outer html structure as well.*

> *2/2 ... The to be used technique is referred to as [Event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) ... [David Walsh :: How JavaScript Event Delegation Works](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) ... [javascript.info :: Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) ... [jQuery :: Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)*

```js
function createTextBoxMarkup(/* value */) {
  return `
    <td>
      <input name = "deliverydate" type="date" class="form-control" id="ldeliverydate"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name = "delivercity" type="text" class="form-control" id="ldelivercity"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name = "deliverstate" type="text" class="form-control" id="ldeliverstate"/>
    </td>`;
}

function handleTextBoxKeyup(evt) {
  const elmInput = evt.target;
  const { type, name, id, value } = elmInput;

  console.log({ elmInput, type, name, id, value });  
}

function init() {
  const elmTBody = document.querySelector('tbody');
  const elmTr = document.createElement('tr');

  elmTr.innerHTML = createTextBoxMarkup();
  elmTBody.appendChild(elmTr);

  // register 'keyup' event type.
  elmTBody.addEventListener('keyup', handleTextBoxKeyup);
}
init();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 83%; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

***Edit** according to further questions of the OP*

> *Can I use something like*
>
> ```
> function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
>   return '<td><input type="text" id="lfuel" onkeyup="count('lfuel');"/></td><td><input type="text" id="lcardfee" onkeyup="count('lcardfee');" /></td>'
> }
> ```
>
> *and then define that count like :*
>
> ```
> function count(id) {
>   if (id == 'lfuel') {
>     var a = document.getElementById('lfuel').value;
>   }
>   if (id == 'lcardfee') {
>     var b = document.getElementById('lcardfee').value;}
> }
> ```
>
> *– Rakhi*

> *Above solution did not worked for me. – Rakhi*

The implementation of `handleTextBoxKeyup` is just example code which demonstrates how information can be extracted from the `event` object. Of cause the OP can implement the handler according to her/his needs e.g. invoking a `count` function from within the handler whenever the `event.target` is an input element of type `"text"`.

```js
function createTextBoxMarkup(/* value */) {
  return `
    <td>
      <input name = "deliverydate" type="date" class="form-control" id="ldeliverydate"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name = "delivercity" type="text" class="form-control" id="ldelivercity"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input name = "deliverstate" type="text" class="form-control" id="ldeliverstate"/>
    </td>`;
}

function isTextTypeInputElement(elmNode) {
  return (
    (elmNode?.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input') &&
    (elmNode?.type === 'text')
  );  
}

function count(elmTextInput) {
  const {  name, id, value } = elmTextInput;

  console.log({ elmTextInput, name, id, value }); 
}

function handleTextBoxKeyup(evt) {
  const elmNode = evt.target;
  if (isTextTypeInputElement(elmNode)) {
  
    count(elmNode);
  }
}

function init() {
  const elmTBody = document.querySelector('tbody');
  const elmTr = document.createElement('tr');

  elmTr.innerHTML = createTextBoxMarkup();
  elmTBody.appendChild(elmTr);

  // register 'keyup' event type.
  elmTBody.addEventListener('keyup', handleTextBoxKeyup);
}
init();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 83%; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

> "I have multiple input fields on which I want to apply onkeyup event on all of them..."

I think this code should accomplish that first requirement.

```
const inputElements = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');

for (let el of inputElements) {
    el.addEventListener('keyup', keyupEventHandler);
}

function keyupEventHandler() {
  console.log(`The input element with id=${this.id} was just modified.`);
  
  if (this.id === '2') {
    alert('Input #2 alert!')
  }
}
```

Notice how the keyword `this` contains the entire element that triggered the keyup event. You can then access that element's ID using `this.id`, thereby circumventing the need to "pass the ID into the event handler" as you initially mentioned.

Regarding this point in your post:

> "I want to be able to do a calculation based on the ID..."

That "calculation" can be done inside of the `keyupEventHandler` function. I added the `if (this.id === '2')` statement as an example of this calculation based on ID.

Fiddle demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/knakamura13/pjzcs384/3/

### EDIT

In response to your comment in the main comment thread, here is code that should work exactly for your needs, using your `count` function:

```
// Get an array of every input element on the page
// Note: use jQuery if installed: $(`input[type="text"]`)
const inputElements = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');

// Iterate over every input element
for (let el of inputElements) {
    // Add the `count` keyup event handler to every input element
    el.addEventListener('keyup', count);
}

// Event handler for keyup events
function count() {
  // Get ID of the element that was used to trigger the event
  const id = this.id;
  
  // Do something with that element's ID
  console.log(id);
}
```

Comment: The query selector result is a node list which contains any kind of `HTMLInputElement` references. Since the OP obviously (from the Q. and the provided code snippet) wants to target text-type input-elements only (and not even then all of them) the correct selector was ... `input[type="text"]` ... `const inputElements = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');`; and `inputElements` is a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) instance which can be iterated with `forEach`, no need of using a `for...of` statement.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I like your suggestion to specify the type=text; I'll update my answer with that addition. However, I was trying to keep things as simple as possible so I used the common `for of` syntax since `forEach` is more of a niche tool that can't be used in any scenario.